# NHibernate map by code, no persister for:

Tags: c#, nhibernate

So I've been struggling with this for about half a day now..
I'm coming eclipselink and java, and for a project I'm making some code with NHibernate and c#.
Unfortunatly documentation about map by code on nhibernate is kind of lacking I guess. I can't find any sources on the errors I'm getting..

For testing purposes I'm working with the Northwind database, so I created a class Customer

```
public class Customer{
    public virtual string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual string ContactName { get; set; }
    public virtual string ContactTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string Region { get; set; }
    public virtual string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string Country { get; set; }
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
    public virtual string Fax { get; set; }
}
```

Also a mapping class:

```
public class CustomerMap: ClassMapping<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap() {
        Schema("dbo");
        Lazy(true);
        Id(x => x.CustomerID, map => map.Generator(Generators.Assigned));
        Property(x => x.CompanyName, map => map.NotNullable(true));
        Property(x => x.ContactName);
        Property(x => x.ContactTitle);
        Property(x => x.Address);
        Property(x => x.City);
        Property(x => x.Region);
        Property(x => x.PostalCode);
        Property(x => x.Country);
        Property(x => x.Phone);
        Property(x => x.Fax);
    }
}
```

But then I get the no persister for error

```
ModelMapper mm = new ModelMapper();
mm.AddMapping<CustomerMap>();
HbmMapping hbmm = mm.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(hbmm.GetType());
xml.Serialize(Console.Out, hbmm);
```

This is the xml that the code above generates

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" namespace="NHibernate.Classes.Domain" assembly="NHibernate, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
      <class name="Customer" schema="dbo">
        <id name="CustomerID" type="String">
          <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="CompanyName" not-null="true" />
        <property name="ContactName" />
        <property name="ContactTitle" />
        <property name="Address" />
        <property name="City" />
        <property name="Region" />
        <property name="PostalCode" />
        <property name="Country" />
        <property name="Phone" />
        <property name="Fax" />
      </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Since I'm working with the map by code stuff I don't want to create this xml myself, so I have no clue what i could be doing wrong. I've searched all over google.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my call to map entities

```
_mapper.AddMappings(MappingAssembly.GetExportedTypes());
           Configure.AddDeserializedMapping(_mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities(), "MyWholeDomain");
```

where _mapper is ModelMapper.  I also explicitly add a config setting to tell the app where my mappings are.  So I load the assembly then call GetExportedTypes()

Here's my whole NhibernateInitializer class

```
public abstract class NHibernateInitializer : IDomainMapper
{
    protected Configuration Configure;
    private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private readonly ModelMapper _mapper = new ModelMapper();
    private Assembly _mappingAssembly;
    private readonly String _mappingAssemblyName;
    private readonly String _connectionString;

    protected NHibernateInitializer(String connectionString, String mappingAssemblyName)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("connectionString", "connectionString is empty.");

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mappingAssemblyName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("mappingAssemblyName", "mappingAssemblyName is empty.");

        _mappingAssemblyName = mappingAssemblyName;
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            return _sessionFactory ?? (_sessionFactory = Configure.BuildSessionFactory());
        }
    }

    private Assembly MappingAssembly
    {
        get
        {
            return _mappingAssembly ?? (_mappingAssembly = Assembly.Load(_mappingAssemblyName));
        }
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        Configure = new Configuration();
        Configure.EventListeners.PreInsertEventListeners = new IPreInsertEventListener[] { new EventListener() };
        Configure.EventListeners.PreUpdateEventListeners = new IPreUpdateEventListener[] { new EventListener() };
        Configure.SessionFactoryName(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionFactoryName"]);
        Configure.DataBaseIntegration(db =>
                                      {
                                          db.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>();
                                          db.Driver<SqlClientDriver>();
                                          db.KeywordsAutoImport = Hbm2DDLKeyWords.AutoQuote;
                                          db.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
                                          db.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
                                          db.BatchSize = 20;
                                          db.Timeout = 10;
                                          db.HqlToSqlSubstitutions = "true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'";
                                      });
        Configure.SessionFactory().GenerateStatistics();

        Map();
    }

    private void Map()
    {
        _mapper.AddMappings(MappingAssembly.GetExportedTypes());
        Configure.AddDeserializedMapping(_mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities(), "MyWholeDomain");
    }

    public HbmMapping HbmMapping
    {
        get { return _mapper.CompileMappingFor(MappingAssembly.GetExportedTypes()); }
    }

    public IList<HbmMapping> HbmMappings
    {
        get { return _mapper.CompileMappingForEach(MappingAssembly.GetExportedTypes()).ToList(); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the domain entities.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <remarks>by default anything that derives from EntityBase and isn't abstract or generic</remarks>
    protected virtual IEnumerable<System.Type> GetDomainEntities()
    {
        List<System.Type> domainEntities = (from t in MappingAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
                                            where typeof(EntityBase<Guid>).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                                            && (!t.IsGenericType || !t.IsAbstract)
                                            select t
                                           ).ToList();

        return domainEntities;
    }
}
```